# else If in tsql

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I must update table, and I can't use else if in tsql. Is it exists?

```
Status =
(
CASE
WHEN
(Status in (0))
THEN
0
ELSE IF Status in (1)
THEN 
7
ELSE
Status
END
```

Comment: Yes, it does exist - but not when your SQL doesnt make sense. Status IN (0)?? What are you trying to achieve???

Comment: It's only example. Actual there will be more more statuses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CASE WHEN syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) does support multiple conditions:

```
Status = CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 0
              WHEN Status = 1 THEN 7
              ELSE Status
         END
```

Since you are comparing the same field for equality in both cases, you can use the shorter notation:

```
Status = CASE Status WHEN 0 THEN 0
                     WHEN 1 THEN 7
                     ELSE Status
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use again CASE WHEN:

```
Status = CASE WHEN Status in (0)
                THEN 0
                ELSE CASE WHEN Status in (1)
                            THEN 7
                            ELSE Status
                     END
         END
```

or

```
Status = CASE WHEN Status in (0) THEN 0
              WHEN Status in (1) THEN 7
              ELSE Status
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following syntax:

```
Status =
    (CASE WHEN (Status in (0)) THEN 0
          WHEN (Status in (1)) THEN 7
          ELSE Status
     END)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 Status =
(
CASE
WHEN
(Status in (0))
THEN
0
WHEN Status in (1)
THEN 
7
ELSE
Status
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can use IF statements in SQL.
Check this

```
   Declare @x int
    set @x = 29
    if @x = 29 print 'The number is 29'
    if @x = 30 print 'The number is 30'
```